# Convertir de decimal a binario recursividad

Tags: java

Tengo que implementar una función recursiva que dado un número decimal inferior a 1024, lo transforme en binario, utilizando como elemento de almacenamiento un array de tipo char. Y tiene que mostrar -> Ejemplo: 10 ---> 0000001010.

Pero la cabecera de la función recursiva debe ser: void conversion(int i, char [] array, int bytes).

Dónde n es el valor que hay que convertir a binario, arrayBin es el array de char inicializado a 0 en cada posición, y nbits el número de bits de nuestro resultado en binario.

```
 public void conversion(int i, char [] array, int bytes) {

        final int LIMITE = 1024;

        if(LIMITE == i) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("El numero debe ser menor a 1024");
        }

        if(0 == i) return;

        int tmpN = i;
        i /= 2;

        //array[array.length-(++bytes)]= (tmpN % 2 == 0) ? '0' : '1';

        conversion(i, array, bytes);

    }
```

He encontrado este código pero no entiendo mucho la parte de código comentado, no se si se podría hacer de otra manera. Por ejemplo de manera recursiva.

Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Saludos, Patrick.

El código que nos muestras **ya es un código recursivo**.

Lo primero que necesitas saber sobre ese código son los argumentos del método `conversion`. Según indicas, los argumentos deberían ser `n`, `arrayBin` y `nbits`. En el código, esos nombres son cambiados por `i`, `array` y `bytes`, pero tal vez eso ya lo sabías.

Lo segundo, es sobre la versión simplicada de la sentencia `if` que se utiliza, esta forma de utilización se denomina **operador ternario**: [clic aquí para ver un ejemplo](http://lineadecodigo.com/java/el-operador-ternario-en-java/). En cualquier caso, lo trataré de explicar un poco:

`array[index]`: Esta es la forma común en la que ingresas valores dentro de un arreglo, utilizando el índice (index) de posición, le indicas en qué posición del arreglo ingresarás el valor asignado después del operador `=`.

El índice de posición (index) **siempre debe ser un valor entero**. En este caso encontramos esto: `array.length - (++bytes)`. Como podemos observar, eso es una operación matemática, que al final nos genera un entero, que se utilizará como índice de posición:

`++bytes`: Esto es un pre-incremento ([este link podría servirte](http://michelletorres.mx/como-funciona-el-operador-de-pre-incremento-y-pre-decremento/)) que su función es aumentar en 1 el valor de `bytes`.

De esa manera, en cada ejecución del método `conversion` se ingresa en cada índice calculado en el arreglo. Pero, ¿qué se almacena en esas posiciones?.

Básicamente, es lo que está después del operador de asignación `=`:

`(tmpN % 2 == 0) ? '0' : '1';`: Esto es un `operador ternario`, realmente, cumple la función de un bloque `if`, lo que está entre paréntesis es la condición que se comprobará, el símbolo `?` indica la operación ternaria, y los dos valores divididos por el símbolo `:` (dos puntos) son los valores que se tomarán si la condición es `true` o `false`, respectivamente.

Entonces, se toma el valor de `tmpN`, se utiliza el operador módulo (símbolo de %) para calcular el `bit` (si es 0 ó 1), y en caso de ser igual a 0, se almacena en el índice calculado previamente el valor de 0, caso contrario, será 1.

Finalmente, al ejecutar el código, aquí está el resultado:

[image: img]